# Como melhorar algoritmo de máximo divisor comum - URI 1028

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou resolvendo [este problema do URI](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1028) que pede, basicamente, que se encontre o máximo divisor comum entre dois valores.

Resolvi originalmente com o `math.gcd` em meia dúzia de linhas, porém, o código não foi aceito já que o URI utiliza uma versão do Python 3 anterior à inclusão do `gcd`. Pois bem, assim resolvi o problema de uma outra maneira:

```
N = int(input())
monte, maior = [], 0

for x in range(N):
    A, B = input().split(' ')
    A, B = int(A), int(B)
    for x in range(A, 1, -1):
        if A % x == 0:
            monte.append(x)
    for x in range(len(monte)):
        if B % monte[x] == 0:
            maior = monte[x]
            break
    print(maior)
```

As saídas estão todas corretas, mas problema é que meu código está sendo recusado por exceder o tempo limite.

Pergunto: Como posso melhorar o mesmo? Já enxuguei tudo o que consegui, mas continua excedendo o tempo limite. Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Veja se alguma dessas soluções te ajuda: [Como implementar um algoritmo de cálculo de MDC recursivo em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/292553/5878)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consegui resolver implementando recursividade graças à dica do @Anderson Carlos Woss no comentário acima.

A quem interessar possa, segue o algoritmo.

```
def mdc(A, B):
return A if not B else mdc(B, A % B)

N = int(input())

for x in range(N):
    A, B = input().split(' ')
    A, B = int(A), int(B)
    print(mdc(A, B))
```

Comment: Usando uma solução recursiva, recomendo considerar usar o decorador [`lru_cache`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/293223/78934) também.

Answer (score 0):

Esta questão se refere ao problema de número **"1028"**, cujo título é **"Figurinhas"**, disponibilizado por **"Uri Online Judge"** (maratona online de programação).

[Veja aqui](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1028) a íntegra do enunciado.

Uma das formas para se resolver esta questão é a seguinte...

```
def mdc(a, b):
    if a % b == 0:
        return b
    else:
        return mdc(b, a % b)


quant_de_testes = int(input())
for c in range(quant_de_testes):
    a = input().split(" ")
    numero1 = int(a[0])
    numero2 = int(a[1])
    print(mdc(numero1, numero2))
```

[Veja aqui](https://repl.it/join/ohscjqqa-solkarped) o funcionamento do algoritmo.